# Resnet is showing wrong predictions even without any object

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, resnet

I was trying to classify between defected plated and not defected plates using resnet. I have a dataset of 2000 images for each of the two categories. But when I tested it in the real-time it is showing "defected" even though there is no object(either fair or defected plate) under the camera.
I am below providing my training code and testing code below. Please try to find out what could be the problem

Testing code:

```
    image =frame
    #print(image.shape)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,160,255,0)
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    height, width, channels = image.shape
    min_x, min_y = width, height
    max_x = max_y = 0
    for cnt in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        if area > 400:
            (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
            min_x, max_x = min(x, min_x), max(x + w, max_x)
            min_y, max_y = min(y, min_y), max(y + h, max_y)
            if (w>200) and (h>200):
                roi1 = image[y:y + h, x:x + w]

                roi = cv2.resize(roi1, (64, 64))
                roi = roi.astype("float") / 255.0
    # order channel dimensions (channels-first or channels-last)
    # depending on our Keras backend, then add a batch dimension to
    # the image
                roi = img_to_array(roi)
                roi = np.expand_dims(roi, axis=0)
    # make predictions on the input image
                pred = model.predict(roi)
                if (pred[0][1]) > .96:
                    label = "Defect"
                    color = (0, 0, 255)
                    confidence = pred[0][1]

                elif (pred[0][0]) > .32:
                    label = "Fair"
                    color = (0, 255, 0)
                    confidence = pred[0][0]             
                #pred = pred.argmax(axis=1)[0]

                # label = "Fair" if pred == 0 else "Defected"
                # color = (0, 255, 0) if pred == 0 else (0, 0, 255)

                cv2.putText(roi1, label, (3, 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5,
                    color, 2)
                cv2.putText(roi1, "confidence:"+str(confidence*100)+"%", (3, 40), 
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5,
                    (255,255,255), 2)
```

Training code:

```
NUM_EPOCHS = 500
BS = 32

# derive the path to the directories containing the training,
# validation, and testing splits, respectively
TRAIN_PATH = os.path.sep.join([args["dataset"], "training"])
VAL_PATH = os.path.sep.join([args["dataset"], "validation"])
TEST_PATH = os.path.sep.join([args["dataset"], "testing"])

# determine the total number of image paths in training, validation,
# and testing directories
totalTrain = len(list(paths.list_images(TRAIN_PATH)))
totalVal = len(list(paths.list_images(VAL_PATH)))
totalTest = len(list(paths.list_images(TEST_PATH)))

# initialize the training training data augmentation object
trainAug = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1 / 255.0,
    rotation_range=20,
    zoom_range=0.05,
    width_shift_range=0.05,
    height_shift_range=0.05,
    shear_range=0.05,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode="nearest")

# initialize the validation (and testing) data augmentation object
valAug = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1 / 255.0)

# initialize the training generator
trainGen = trainAug.flow_from_directory(
    TRAIN_PATH,
    class_mode="categorical",
    target_size=(64, 64),
    color_mode="rgb",
    shuffle=True,
    batch_size=32)

# initialize the validation generator
valGen = valAug.flow_from_directory(
    VAL_PATH,
    class_mode="categorical",
    target_size=(64, 64),
    color_mode="rgb",
    shuffle=False,
    batch_size=BS)

# initialize the testing generator
testGen = valAug.flow_from_directory(
    TEST_PATH,
    class_mode="categorical",
    target_size=(64, 64),
    color_mode="rgb",
    shuffle=False,
    batch_size=BS)

# initialize our Keras implementation of ResNet model and compile it
model = ResNet.build(64, 64, 3, 2, (2, 2, 3),
    (32, 64, 128, 256), reg=0.0005)
opt = SGD(lr=1e-1, momentum=0.9, decay=1e-1 / NUM_EPOCHS)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,
    metrics=["accuracy"])

# train our Keras model
H = model.fit_generator(
    trainGen,
    steps_per_epoch=totalTrain // BS,
    validation_data=valGen,
    validation_steps=totalVal // BS,
    epochs=NUM_EPOCHS)

# reset the testing generator and then use our trained model to
# make predictions on the data
print("[INFO] evaluating network...")
testGen.reset()
predIdxs = model.predict_generator(testGen,
    steps=(totalTest // BS) + 1)

# for each image in the testing set we need to find the index of the
# label with corresponding largest predicted probability
predIdxs = np.argmax(predIdxs, axis=1)

# show a nicely formatted classification report
print(classification_report(testGen.classes, predIdxs,
    target_names=testGen.class_indices.keys()))

# save the network to disk
print("[INFO] serializing network to '{}'...".format(args["model"]))
model.save(args["model"])
```

When I was testing through video, it was showing an affinity towards the defected plates, confidence score for fair plates were very less and that for defected plates were very high.

Answer (score 0):

The output of such a network is a probability across classes. This does not include a 'nothing' class, unless you make it so. If you're in a lab environment (as it sounds) then perhaps the regularity of your testing area might permit this. The network will always have *some* highest scoring output class, even if they are all extremely low, although with softmax activation the sum across classes will always equal one. There are some methods for handling this in various scenarios, but largely it's considered an area of urgent active research.

Beyond that, the performance of your network is unable to be predicted; that's the entire field of AI application. You'll need to improve it experimentally.

Comment: So what do you suggest using binary_crossentropy or categorical, and any other activation functions or something

Comment: You could try binary crossentropy loss with a sigmoid output activation function and get a value on interval [0,1] of probability for each class, not summing to one (as it does with softmax). However, My thought was that if you're using this in a controlled environment you could just slap a big pink "X" down with colored tape on the table beneath your camera, ideally blocked when you're checking a plate. Then you could train the big pink "X" to class "nothing."

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion, let me try and I will get back to you with the result review