# How to get prediction and confidence of that prediction using resnet

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

I have a binary classifier which predicts whether the image is positive or negative. I am using model.predict for getting the detections. So basically what I want is the class index and the confidence value with which it belongs to that class. I am able to get the detections and able to show it on the image, but for background images also it is showing some false predictions so I would like to remove those by setting a threshold for the confidence. For information about the training file and testing file I have asked a question on StackOverflow, please refer the link "[Resnet is showing wrong predictions even without any object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60474340/resnet-is-showing-wrong-predictions-even-without-any-object)"

[image: This is the class with index 1]

[image: This is the class with index 0]

My Resnet code:

```
# import the necessary packages
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import AveragePooling2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import ZeroPadding2D
from keras.layers.core import Activation
from keras.layers.core import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import add
from keras.regularizers import l2
from keras import backend as K

class ResNet:
    @staticmethod
    def residual_module(data, K, stride, chanDim, red=False,
        reg=0.0001, bnEps=2e-5, bnMom=0.9):
        # the shortcut branch of the ResNet module should be
        # initialize as the input (identity) data
        shortcut = data

        # the first block of the ResNet module are the 1x1 CONVs
        bn1 = BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim, epsilon=bnEps,
            momentum=bnMom)(data)
        act1 = Activation("relu")(bn1)
        conv1 = Conv2D(int(K * 0.25), (1, 1), use_bias=False,
            kernel_regularizer=l2(reg))(act1)

        # the second block of the ResNet module are the 3x3 CONVs
        bn2 = BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim, epsilon=bnEps,
            momentum=bnMom)(conv1)
        act2 = Activation("relu")(bn2)
        conv2 = Conv2D(int(K * 0.25), (3, 3), strides=stride,
            padding="same", use_bias=False,
            kernel_regularizer=l2(reg))(act2)

        # the third block of the ResNet module is another set of 1x1
        # CONVs
        bn3 = BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim, epsilon=bnEps,
            momentum=bnMom)(conv2)
        act3 = Activation("relu")(bn3)
        conv3 = Conv2D(K, (1, 1), use_bias=False,
            kernel_regularizer=l2(reg))(act3)

        # if we are to reduce the spatial size, apply a CONV layer to
        # the shortcut
        if red:
            shortcut = Conv2D(K, (1, 1), strides=stride,
                use_bias=False, kernel_regularizer=l2(reg))(act1)

        # add together the shortcut and the final CONV
        x = add([conv3, shortcut])

        # return the addition as the output of the ResNet module
        return x

    @staticmethod
    def build(width, height, depth, classes, stages, filters,
        reg=0.0001, bnEps=2e-5, bnMom=0.9):
        # initialize the input shape to be "channels last" and the
        # channels dimension itself
        inputShape = (height, width, depth)
        chanDim = -1

        # if we are using "channels first", update the input shape
        # and channels dimension
        if K.image_data_format() == "channels_first":
            inputShape = (depth, height, width)
            chanDim = 1

        # set the input and apply BN
        inputs = Input(shape=inputShape)
        x = BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim, epsilon=bnEps,
            momentum=bnMom)(inputs)

        # apply CONV => BN => ACT => POOL to reduce spatial size
        x = Conv2D(filters[0], (5, 5), use_bias=False,
            padding="same", kernel_regularizer=l2(reg))(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim, epsilon=bnEps,
            momentum=bnMom)(x)
        x = Activation("relu")(x)
        x = ZeroPadding2D((1, 1))(x)
        x = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(x)

        # loop over the number of stages
        for i in range(0, len(stages)):
            # initialize the stride, then apply a residual module
            # used to reduce the spatial size of the input volume
            stride = (1, 1) if i == 0 else (2, 2)
            x = ResNet.residual_module(x, filters[i + 1], stride,
                chanDim, red=True, bnEps=bnEps, bnMom=bnMom)

            # loop over the number of layers in the stage
            for j in range(0, stages[i] - 1):
                # apply a ResNet module
                x = ResNet.residual_module(x, filters[i + 1],
                    (1, 1), chanDim, bnEps=bnEps, bnMom=bnMom)

        # apply BN => ACT => POOL
        x = BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim, epsilon=bnEps,
            momentum=bnMom)(x)
        x = Activation("relu")(x)
        x = AveragePooling2D((8, 8))(x)

        # softmax classifier
        x = Flatten()(x)
        x = Dense(classes, kernel_regularizer=l2(reg))(x)
        x = Activation("softmax")(x)

        # create the model
        model = Model(inputs, x, name="resnet")

        # return the constructed network architecture
        return model
```

Any kind of suggestion to get rid of my this problem would be really helpful

Comment: your output activation must be `softmax`? It does exactly what you want, outputs probability of every sample belonging to number of classes. And then you just choose the max of these probabs to get the prediction. Instead of doing the max you can use your logic.

Comment: Hi Siddhant, thanks for the comment. I have been using softmax in the last layer. For clarification I have updated my resnet code in the question, please have a look and give me your suggestions and what changes do I have to make. Also how to index for the confidence of particular class would also be helpful for me.

Comment: I think you already have it. The SO question that you attached in the link, you have this line `predIdxs = np.argmax(predIdxs, axis=1)`. `predIdxs` is the probability that your sample belongs to a class. It will be a list of probabs like `[0.2,0.8]`, so this means your input image has 80% confidence in class 2, and 20% conf in class1. And then you can set a threshold or whatever you want. You already have the probabs, you just need to modify things outside your class when you do `predIdxs = np.argmax(predIdxs, axis=1)`

Comment: Okay Thanks, Siddhant, suppose I have 3 classes the last one being the background class and I am using categorical cross-entropy, then how to get a particular class and corresponding confidence of that class